# MongoDB aggregation (via MongoEngine/PyMongo): can I access ReferenceField objects?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

suppose I have two model classes like so:

```
class Institution(Model):
    name = StringField()

class Student(Model):
    full_name = StringField()
    institution = ReferenceField(Institution)
```

Is it possible to access `Student.institution.name` in an aggregation pipeline?

Comment: Can you show your query? If what you are asking is how to get `name` from `Student` object then Yes! You can do `s.institution.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***From monogdb version 3.2*** this is possible with [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) but with some limitations (e.g. won't work on sharded collections), example:

```
db.student.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "institution",
          localField: "institution",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "institution"
        }
   }
])
```